# Why do LiveUSBs use squashfs (and similar) file systems?

Tags: filesystems, usb-drive, live-usb, squashfs

Every LiveUSB I have encountered so far uses squashfs or some similar method of "faking" and ext4 file system, while actually keeping the partition type already found on the USB flash drive.

Why don't Linux LiveUSBs just format the USB drive to `ext4` like it does with internal harddrives?

Answer (score 3):

Squashfs is often used in association with an union FS (overlayfs, aufs) to create immutable live images.

Meaning that squashfs image is mounted readonly, and a tmpfs is mounted readwrite. We then assemble these two layers and mount them as an union on /. These assembly and mounting steps are usually done in initramfs before chrooting to the assembled root file system.

All readonly accesses are made directly to squashfs image, while all changes are commited to tmpfs, in RAM, volatile, so that next boot, image will be left unchanged.

IMHO, using squashfs readwrite is less relevant. In that case, unless you really have a space constraint to meet, you should rather use ext4 like you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

squashfs is faster, especially with slow media like USB flash is.
Boot from squashfs produce less IO because data is effectively compressed and metadata isn't so complicated.
squashfs have some drawbacks: it is cpu-hungry, it does not allow any data modification, so it isn't widely used on desktop, but it suits well for tasks like liveUSB.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is that the unpacked image while booting will expand itself, but where ?

If it would be on RAM, the computer may not have enough of it to make it so. But if it would be done on the usb key itself on an ext4 partition, the "image" would not be intact anymore, since file are written on the same partition.

Even worse, some changes can make the changes persistent, which you do not want to happen on an image.

Comment: But even distros on USB which allow you to save changes between reboots use squashfs. In fact, such systems require you to define ahead of time how much space will be reserved for changes, rather than just use the entire available space.

Comment: This is the problem of keeping the image intact, even if "changes" can be made. Ext 4 is not a read-only filesystem and means, that if you plan to install the system after you've modified it, you won't have a clean and bug-free image. And even in the eventuality that you want do a installation of a modified system, remember that the images must expand itself, meaning that the modifications will not fir the iso's hierarchy (no /etc, /home, etc inside the iso) ;)